# Get data config return array

Tags: php

i have two php files  config.php look like this:

config.php :

```
<?php 
return array(
   'name' => 'Demo',
   'age'  => 21,
   'job'  => 'Coder'
);
?>
```

in file index.php, i using file_get_contents for get data of file config.php

index.php:

```
$config = file_get_contents('config.php');

echo $config['name'];
```

but this is not working. somebody can help me?

Comment: you have to include it not read the file contents.do this: include("config.php");

Comment: if using include('config.php');, how to echo value of array in file config.php?

Comment: do this way: $somevar = include("config.php"); echo $somevar["name"];

Answer (score 2):

You `include` code and not its output.

```
$config = file_get_contents('config.php');
```

Sends your file to PHP and generates the output and then sends it back to you, which is not what you have to do for code. You have to do

```
$config = include('config.php'); // or require / require_once / include_once
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `file_get_contents(file)` reads the entire file into a string. That means that it will return a string represntation of the content of the file and NOT source code that you can just use in your main script.

- Note: If the path to file is an absolute path, `file_get_contents()` will execute the php first and return the rendered output of the php file.

Since you want the source of 'config.php' to be available in 'index.php', you have to `include` it.

Just use `include()` or `include_once()`.

config.php :

```
<? 
$config =  array(
   'name' => 'Demo',
   'age'  => 21,
   'job'  => 'Coder'
);
?>
```

index.php:

```
include('config.php');//or include_once('config.php');
//include makes the content of 'config.php' available exactly as if it was written inside of the document iteself.

echo $config['name'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a wrong statement `The function file_get_contents() reads the file into a string, it does not execute it`. It does execute the code in the file and then it returns the output

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I modifed my answer per your comment. My original comment was not wrong actually because he was using a relative path in his example. As far as I know and tested it, file_get_contents() will execute and return the rendered output only when using abolute path. Would love to hear your insights on it.